Auto fix old typing types pep 585 python
Is there any tool that auto fixes typing imports coming from the typing module that could be typed from the built-in collection (PEP 585)?
From:
from typing import Any, Dict
my_dict = Dict[str, Any]

To:
from typing import Any
my_dict = dict[str, Any]

It'd be nice if there is a tool that can auto-fix these. We currently use black in our project but it does not seem to have config for this yet

You can use a tool like ruff, which provides auto-fixable lints to fix PEP585 imports and remove unused imports.
For instance, you can configure a ruff.toml config file at the root of your project directory as such:
target-version = "py310"

[lint]
select = ["UP006", "F401"] # UP006 applies PEP585, F401 removes unused imports

Running ruff --fix your_project_dir will then auto-apply changes to your project.
